# Appending to same line in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am not sure if this is even possible but here it goes:

I am writing a script that calls to another batch file for a command. The 1st script has a loop to ask the user question and sets their input as a variable. After the variable is created I need to insert that variable into the 2nd script, however, this is where i get stuck. I can't just do this:

```
echo >> %var%
```

The variables need to go on the same line. So i have a couple of options. I can append the variables to the 2nd script or I can prepend it to the 2nd script (if that is easier). I assume that there is a way that you can do it with a for loop but every time I try that it does not come out right. So this is what i need the 2nd script to look like:

```
command /%currentvar% /%newvar% /%newvar%
```

I orginally tried to build an array of variables then insert the array as a variable into the 2nd script but I have come to the conclusion that this is not possible. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You cannot append each time to the same variable (with the separator that you want) and, at the end, insert that variable in the 2nd script?

Comment: ok i was not sure if i could do this or not. Also yes the variables are coming from the first script and inserted into the second script.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the variable to 2nd batch file as command line arg:

```
CALL file2.bat %var%
```

Then get the value of `var` with `%1`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I didnt think about that but im going to have an unknown amount of variables being set and written into the second batch file.

Comment: I think the environment is inherited by called batch file - you can use them directly e.g. `%var%`.

Comment: @i486 - That's true, I just tested it. So there is no need to pass any parameter to the 2nd batch file. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to combine the variables into a string, and in 1st batch file call the 2nd batch file passing the combined variable.

```
call 2nd.bat %combined%
```

Then in 2nd.bat you can access all command line parameters using `%*`

So 1st.bat would look someting like:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set combined=

for %%i in (1, 2, 3) do (
    set /p "input=Enter variable%%i: "
    set combined=!combined! /!input!
)

call 2nd.bat %combined%
```

And 2nd.bat would look like:

```
command %*
```

Comment: Originally I attempted to string the variables together. After my attempt I thought that it could not be possible in batch. I guess I was doing it wrong. How would you do it?

Comment: If you want " /" at the start of each part, you can do this: set combined=%combined% /theNextOne

Comment: ohhh ok. That is almost exactly how i did it the first time with out putting it in a for loop. I will give that a shot. Thanks!